# Where should I store machine-wide application settings for non-roaming users?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, application-data, roaming-profile

I have a WPF application that must run for all users of *a machine* with the same settings. The settings must be read/write. I have previously been storing user configuration settings in CommonApplicationData, for example

```
var settingsFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
  Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
    "[company]", "[product]", "settings.xml");
```

However I read this morning that `CommonApplicationData` is used for roaming profiles, meaning they are not machine specific. From what I can find, we have the following options for application data ([source](http://vbcity.com/blogs/mike-mcintyre/archive/2011/07/10/storing-user-application-data-on-windows-computer.aspx)):

```
// Store application-specific data for the current roaming user.
// A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network.
// A roaming user's profile is kept on a server on the network and is loaded onto a system ' when the user logs on.
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);


// Store in-common application-specific data that is used by all users.
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);


// Store application-specific data that is used by the current, non-roaming user.
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

To summarize, the options are

- Single user, roaming
- All users, roaming
- Single user, non-roaming

What I need is all users, non-roaming. My initial thought is to chuck it all into the install folder, but that seems a little old-school?

Thoughts?

Comment: Where did you read that `CommonApplicationData` is roaming? I find it a bit strange...

Comment: I read it in Bill Wagner's book Effective C#. However that's the only place I can find this tidbit so maybe it's a rare mistake on Wagner's part, and I'd be very interested in hearing if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) documentation: "The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users."

Comment: Maybe I don't understand roaming properly, so perhaps this is obvious from that brief description, but what if one or more of those users is a roaming user?

Comment: There is no default folder in the standard install of Windows where *all* users have write access.  You'll have to create one yourself.

Comment: The write access isn't an issue, I'm granting write access in my installer. Thanks though :)

Comment: Already an old post, but I use this solution with success
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752048/config-file-location-for-any-user-workstation-specific-config#14752549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a good explanation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489%28WS.10%29.aspx) of the appdata folder and other items related to roaming user.

According to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx):

`CommonApplicationData` is "the directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users"

whereas

`LocalApplicationData` is "the directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the current, non-roaming user".

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this is [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) which can be application wide or per user as you wish per setting.

Comment: Application scoped settings cannot be altered at runtime, so they're only suitable for values that never change.  It might work for op, but probably not based on his specific question.